# pexpect sftp: source file as file object

Tags: python, sftp, pexpect

Is it possible not to read the file to be transferred from the file system? I get files from a server and want sftp them to another. I'd rather not write them to the file system first.

Is there a way to read from a file object instead?

Comment: What is wrong with just storing their contents in memory? (probably only one chunk at a time)

Comment: Have you got a file-like object connected to the first server?

Comment: @larsmans @ulidtko The file lives as an attachment in a couchdb database. I fetch the attachment and store it for the duration of the script as a file object. From here I'd like to send the file to the next server.